# TypeError: event.watch is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm following this [tutorial](https://blog.goodaudience.com/ethereum-ipfs-react-dapp-tutorial-pt-1-a9dfd5079491) and when I'm using truffle test to test my React app, I keep getting the following exception error thrown:

`TypeError: event.watch is not a function`
I am sure the event is present in `IPFSInboxTests.js`. Here is `IPFSInboxTests.js` looks like:
[image]
And this is how IPFSInbox.sol code looks like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract IPFSInbox {

mapping (address => string) ipfsInbox;

event ipfsSent(string _ipfsHash, address _address);
event inboxResponse(string response);

modifier notFull (string memory _string) {bytes memory stringTest = bytes(_string); require (stringTest.length == 0); _;}

constructor() public {
}

function sendIPFS(address _address, string memory _ipfsHash)
    notFull(ipfsInbox[_address])
    public
{   
   ipfsInbox[_address] = _ipfsHash;
   emit ipfsSent(_ipfsHash, _address);
}

function checkInbox() public
{
    string memory ipfs_hash = ipfsInbox[msg.sender];
    if(bytes(ipfs_hash).length == 0) {
        emit inboxResponse("Empty Inbox");
    } else {
        ipfsInbox[msg.sender] = "";
        emit inboxResponse(ipfs_hash);
    }
}}
```

after I do truffle migrate

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\ipfs-ethereum-tutorial>truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\IPFSInbox.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\ipfs-ethereum-tutorial\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang

Network up to date.
```

the error I get after do truffle test looks like:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\ipfs-ethereum-tutorial>truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



  Contract: IPFSInbox
    1) ...should emit an event when you send an IPFS address.
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (88ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: IPFSInbox
       ...should emit an event when you send an IPFS address.:
     TypeError: event.watch is not a function
      at Context.it (test\ IPFSInboxTests.js:9:21)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I can't figure it out. Can someone please help?

Comment: can u update the migrate and test code. P/S: i dont think that the error font color is easy to read on black background

Comment: After changing `event.watch` to `events.event `, I get an error `ReferenceError: events is not defined`.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? cause I don't know how to solve this incompatible problem. I'm new here.

Comment: Are you using ganache as a testnet?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ganache-cli as a testnet.

Comment: Okay so just like the problem form that answer, ganache-cli haven't support websocket yet so the only way to check event on ganache is contract.getPastEvents: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents and then check if the event work. I suggest you do some command with truffle console first then when you get the hang of it, write down the console command you type in to js file.

Comment: After changing `events.event` to `event.getPastEvents` and entering `truffle compile`, 'truffle migrate, and `truffle test`, I still get an error `TypeError: event.getPastEvents is not a function` . Now, I don't know what to do.

Comment: that's should be ipfsInbox.getPastEvents because like the document says myContract.getPastEvents